# Error Migrating from Spring 3.2.2 to 4.0.2

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

We are trying to migrate a Spring MVC application from 3.2.2 to 4.0.2 and receive the below error.

The `.jar` files in the `lib` folder are (all below jar files have been changed to 4.0.2 version):

```
    spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar    spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
    spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar    spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
    spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar    spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar

Also added one more jar : spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE
```

ERROR:

```
[9/28/15 1:43:54:731 EDT] 00000026 ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E: Uncaught service() exception root cause /xbnp/sprin
g/BenefitDistributionParameter.jsp: com.ibm.websphere.servlet.error.ServletErrorReport: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/InputTag.
setDisabled&#40;Ljava/lang/String&#59;&#41;V
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:695)
        at com.ibm._jsp._BenefitDistributionParameter._jspService(_BenefitDistributionParameter.java:1953)
        at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/InputTag.setDisabled(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at com.ibm._jsp._BenefitDistributionParameter._jspx_meth_spring_input_1(_BenefitDistributionParameter.java:2010)
        at com.ibm._jsp._BenefitDistributionParameter._jspService(_BenefitDistributionParameter.java:624)
```

How can we  rectify this error?

Comment: Don't just change jars, I strongly suggest using something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies. Don't go downloading the internet and see which combinations work....

Comment: Thanks Deinum, It got resolved.

Existing Code:
InputTag obj = new  InputTag();
obj.setDisabled("true");//STRING argument

New Code :
InputTag obj = new  InputTag();
obj.setDisabled(true);//BOOLEAN argument